# PHP Session advice needed please

Tags: php, html

I'm learning PHP and need a little help if possible.

I know I'm missing something simple her but can't figure it out, I have got the following piece of PHP to transfer users from a page they have just entered their username and password on, to the next page of the site called `homepage.php`. This script needs to generate a session name but I'm unsure were to put it.

I then need a small piece of PHP to then check the user name and password is correct before loading the page for the user to see, does this make sense and can anyone help?

```
<?php 
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // username
$password=""; // password
$db_name="gotswapuser"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");


$myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']);
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mypassword']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE name='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
    header("location:homepage.php");
} else {
  header("location:subscriptionpage.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/) for database access, not mysql.  Mysql is in the process of being deprecated, and is not good practice.

To answer your question, however:

Using the code that you have, you just want to add a few lines on the "successful" login:

```
 if($count==1) {  
     session_start();  
     $_SESSION["logged_in"] = 1;  
     header("location:homepage.php");  
 } else {  
   header("location:subscriptionpage.php");  
 }
```

Then, on the page where the user should be logged in, do something like so:

```
 session_start();
 if ( ! isset($_SESSION["logged_in"]) || ! $_SESSION["logged_in"]) {
      header("location:signin.php");
      exit;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL commands are being depreciated, you should consider Mysqli or PDO, but other than that you should start the session within the if clause

```
         if(found){
             session_start();
             $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
              redirect user
           }
          rest of code.....
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to start your session. See below:

```
session_start();
```

After starting your session, you can store and retrieve variables using the $_SESSION superglobal. See below:

```
$_SESSION['me'] = 'John Doe';
$_SESSION['you'] = 'Jane Doe';
$_SESSION['us'] = 'Doe Family';

echo $_SESSION['us'];
```

Just make sure to always use session_start(); before trying to access these variables. Read more on PHP.net HERE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Once session_start() has been ran, you can easily retrieve the session ID using the session_id() function. If you have not used session_start(), it will return null. See below:

```
echo session_id(); // Returns session ID.
```

Hope this helps! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

your almost there. you just need to:
1, make sure that your session has been started: `session_start();`
2, create a session variable for your username: `$_SESSION['username'] = $result[0]['username'];`

```
if($count==1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $result[0]['username'];
    header("location:homepage.php");
} else {
  header("location:subscriptionpage.php");
}
```

a couple of things to suggest. after calling your mysql statement fetch the row or object in order to be able to bring in your username for your session.